# Change directory in Jenkins using shell script in YML pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, cd

I have written a YML Pipeline in Jenkins. I cloned code using ssh from BitBucket. The code directory is inside the jenkins_pipeline directory. I have to run a few `sh` commands using the YML script. I want to change the directory at the start of the script to the code directory so that I no longer need to change it in every `sh` command. I am not getting a way to do this. Here is my YML script. I have tried using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd#:%7E:text=To%20change%20the%20current%20shell%27s,instead%20of%20a%20sub%20shell.&text=You%20should%20add%20this%20to,can%20run%20this%20as%20%24%20cdproj%20.) method but it always says script.sh file not found which is there in the directory.
**YML script**

```
    pipeline:
  environment:
  agent:
    any:
  stages:
    - stage: Pull Code and Merge master in UAT
      steps:
        script:
          - sh 'git clone ssh://url-to-repo'            
          - sh 'source script.sh'     #it gives the error
          - sh 'pwd'
          - sh 'git checkout release/uat'
          - sh "git pull "
          - sh 'git status'
          - sh 'git merge -m "merging changes from main to UAT" origin/master'
          - sh 'git push'
    - stage: Content Replace
      steps:
        script:
          - withEnv: "['FIND_SER_NAME=dev','REPLACE_SER_NAME=uat']"
            script:
              - "contentReplace(configs: [fileContentReplaceConfig(configs: [fileContentReplaceItemConfig(matchCount: 0, replace: env.REPLACE_SER_NAME, search: env.FIND_SER_NAME)], fileEncoding: 'UTF-8', filePath: '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/UAT_YamlPipeline_Ceye_Service/deploy.sh')])"   
    - stage: Publish Changes to uat branch
      steps:
        script:
          - sh 'git status'
          - sh 'git add --all'
          - sh 'git commit -m "[CYB-128]changed the IPs for UAT branch for build"'
          - sh "git push  --all"
```

**this is my currently working script**

```
    pipeline:
  environment:
  agent:
    any:
  stages:
    - stage: Pull Code and Merge master in UAT
      steps:
        script:
          - sh ' cd ceye-service && git checkout release/uat'
          - sh " cd ceye-service && git pull "
          - sh ' cd ceye-service && git status'
          - sh ' cd ceye-service && git merge -m "merging changes from main to UAT" origin/master'
          - sh ' cd ceye-service && git push'
    - stage: Content Replace
      steps:
        script:
          - withEnv: "['FIND_SER_NAME=dev','REPLACE_SER_NAME=uat']"
            script:
              - "contentReplace(configs: [fileContentReplaceConfig(configs: [fileContentReplaceItemConfig(matchCount: 0, replace: env.REPLACE_SER_NAME, search: env.FIND_SER_NAME)], fileEncoding: 'UTF-8', filePath: '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/uat-ceye_service_code_change/ceye-service/deploy.sh')])"   
    - stage: Publish Changes to uat branch
      steps:
        script:
          - sh ' cd ceye-service && git status'
          - sh 'cd ceye-service && git add --all'
          - sh 'cd ceye-service && git commit -m "[CYB-128]changed the IPs for UAT branch for build"'
          - sh "cd ceye-service && git push --all"
```

I don't want to us `cd` in every command. Is there a way I could switch directory in start and it stay until the script ends? Thanks a lot

Comment: What kind of plugin do you use to enable yaml based pipeline? I've seen some plugin using the `dir` command as a sort of wrapper (as its a special step with code block):
```steps:
      script:
        - dir: 'ceye-service'
          script:
            - sh 'git status' 
```

EDIT: Removed the other sh commands

Comment: Made a typo at dir, it should be `dir: "'ceye-service'"`

Comment: @Unforgettable631 I am using this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-as-yaml

Comment: @Unforgettable631 could you please write your script in a formatted way? I am getting confused with indentations. Would you please add that to my question? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markup, as comment doesn't have proper indentation: can you try this?

```
pipeline:
  environment:
  agent:
    any:
  stages:
    - stage: Pull Code and Merge master in UAT
      steps:
        script:
          - dir: "'ceye-service'"
            script:
              - sh 'git checkout release/uat'
              - sh "git pull"
              - sh 'git status'
              - sh 'git merge -m "merging changes from main to UAT" origin/master'
              - sh 'git push'
```

Documentation https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-as-yaml/ specific the part of `Special Steps With Code Blocks` describes this.

*Some steps has their own code blocks. For example: 'withAnt, withEnv, withCredentials, dir' or any other custom step definition which has it's own code block.
This kind of steps also can be defined as YAML.*

Comment: that worked. Thanks. There's one more question. Can I specify the directory at the start of the script as I am having multiple stages in my yml script?

Comment: Do you mean specify the directory at the top once for multiple stages / steps? I did not try that earlier. If you have access to your converter `https://jenkins-url/payConverter/` you can paste your YAML example and when it converts to `Pipeline Declarative Script` (and click on `Validate`) to your expectation, then my guess it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I will try it out.